# Sed in mac creates a duplicate file in mac

Tags: macos, shell, sed, scripting

I use any one of the following commands to remove all lines after the word 'Generated'. 
This works fine in linux. But not in mac!!

```
sed -i' ' '/Generated/q' file_name
sed -i '' '/Generated/q' file_name
```

In mac, it performs the change to a new file. So my subsequent commands are not able to run.

Please let me know what I need to change!

Note: But on the contrary the following command (find and replace) works fine in both mac and linux.

```
sed -i '' -e '$ s/,/;/g' file_name
```

Comment: try if `sed '/Generated/{q;}'` or `sed '/Generated/{q}'` works...

Comment: @Sundeep: What about the -i option? Is that needed?

Comment: first see if it works, then use `-i ''` for inplace editing...